# Can't escape semicolons in a MySQL UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I am currently having an issue with a **MySQL UPDATE** statement I am working with. For some reason I am unable to escape the semicolons in the statement.

If I remove all the semi-colons from the statement it works fine, so I know it has something to do with escaping the semi-colons.

I've tried the standard method of escaping them by preceding them with a `\`, however that does nothing.

I've also tried switching/swapping out all the single quotes for double quotes, and double quotes for single quotes, to reverse the ordering of them, which also does nothing.

Here is the statement I am trying to execute:

```
UPDATE email_campaign_template 
                SET content='<style>
/* General */
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    color: #fdfcfc;
}
.container {
    max-width: 660px;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
'
                WHERE label='Property Flyer 01' 
                AND email_campaign_id = '10';
```

This generates the following error, which is referring to the first semicolon in the statement:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ''<style> /* General */ body {    font-family: "Open Sans",
>   sans-serif' at line 2

**How can I successfully escape the semi-colons in order to be able to execute this RAW MySQL statement?**

Comment: you mention php. Please show the full php instruction containing this query.

Comment: Use a Heredoc. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Actually at this point I've isolated the issue down to something outside of any PHP, to just the query statement itself. I will remove the PHP tag.

Comment: which php function are you using to run the query? pdo? something else?

Comment: The error message apparently complains about the line feed. Why do you mention semicolons? Said that, do yourself a favour and don't escape stuff manually: use prepared statements and let PHP do the job for you.

Comment: Please refrain from suggesting solutions using PHP. This is a raw MySQL statement. I understand how to escape strings in PHP, but what I am trying to figure out is why this raw MySQL statement does not work. I've tried executing it using Navicat, Workbench, and even command line.

Comment: @McWayWeb - I'm puzzled. I cannot reproduce your syntax error with regular clients (command-line, Workbench or HeidiSQL) but it happens with sqlfiddle.com—yet SQL Fiddle has a custom SQL parser that's not reliable. Even then, it doesn't complain about semicolons, which do not have any special meaning inside SQL strings.

Comment: You and be both. Still not quite sure why it was happening. I ended up just preparing and executing it through PHP, which worked fine. But I still never understood why the SQL was giving me an issue in the first place .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CHAR(59) whenever you want to put a semicolon in a string.

Answer (score -1):

You can sanitize your query with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

See documentation for implementation. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score -2):

You can use a Heredoc to escape large segments of code or text

```
  $text = <<<HEREDOC
'<style>
    /* General */
    body {
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        color: #fdfcfc;
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 660px;
    }
    * {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    </style>
HEREDOC;

      UPDATE email_campaign_template 
                    SET content= '$text'
                    WHERE label='Property Flyer 01' 
                    AND email_campaign_id = '10';
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it may be because your code is really no different to the OPs "pseudo-code" and you aren't actually "escaping" anything.

Comment: I added a heredoc which should escape everything enclosed within

Comment: Heredoc syntax is simply another way to delimit a string literal, it does not "escape" anything. In order to _escape_ the string (to prevent SQL-injection) you need to either call [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or (preferably) use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: He isn't asking how to escape it to prevent sql injection though, he's asking how to make his query not give him an error.

Comment: The point is that heredoc syntax does nothing to help this situation. Escaping to prevent "SQL injection" or escaping to prevent "a SQL error" is the same thing.